# Efficient GridView Paging... not quite getting it

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview

I'm trying to wrap my head around custom paging in the ASP.NET Gridview, but all of the examples I read seem to be bloated with stuff I don't need ([Scott Gu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/07/434787.aspx)'s for example).

Can someone point me in the right direction to a tutorial that is easy to understand the basics?

EXAMPE: If I have the following Stored Procedure...

```
Alter Procedure dbo.GetReqeusts

@Category nvarchar(50)

As
Begin
  Select dbo.[Name], 
         dbo.[ID] 
  From   dbo.[Table] 
  Where  dbo.[Category] = @Category
End
```

And this example returns 200 rows, how would I convert this Stored Procedure into an efficient paging procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4guysfromrolla.com have a whole series of articles about [working with and displaying data](https://web.archive.org/web/20200627014848/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com:80/2.0/#DispData2). There are several about [custom paging](https://web.archive.org/web/20210510021915/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031506-1.aspx).

The key point for the stored procedure is to use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function to restrict the records to be returned:

```
SELECT RowNum, [Name], [ID]
FROM
   (SELECT [Name], [ID]
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [ID]) as RowNum
    FROM [Table] t
    WHERE [Category] = @Category
   ) as DerivedTableName
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN @startRowIndex AND (@startRowIndex + @maximumRows) - 1
```

Comment: yeah I looked at that example several times but it makes no sense to me... sorry. I'm hoping to find an A/B (normal)/(efficient) so that I can see the differences.

Comment: the (dot dot dot), and the (From Employees e) kinda confuses me

Comment: I think this one makes a bit more sense http://www.nikhedonia.com/notebook/entry/efficient-paging-for-gridview/

Comment: The example I had used was taken from the article linked in the answer. I tried to adapt it to your sample code. Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok,so I got this working, however I do have one little problem... I want EVERYTHING to populate in grid in DESC order.  IE: I want to start with the last row and move up... how can I do this?

Comment: @rockinthesixstring: You have to modify the *inner select query* to return the results in the desired order: e.g. `... WHERE [Category] = @Category ORDER BY [Category] DESC`

Comment: Yeah I tried that, but I got the following `The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified`

Comment: I also tried putting in "Top 10000000" just to see, but it still lists the records in reverse.

Comment: sorry, this seems to have fixed it `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [ID] Desc) as RowNum`